# Send a message from an iPhone to a Mac

Tags: macos, iphone

Is there a way to send messages from an iPhone (iOS 7.0.3) to a Mac (OS X Mavericks) to show on the screen?

For example, imagine I’m in the kitchen and I want to send a message that will show on the iMac’s screen to my son, who is upstairs in his room. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: which iOS version iPhone and mac version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [imessage](http://www.apple.com/ios/messages/). and with [OS X Mavericks](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/#notifications)  you can take it as notifications too.

[image: notifications]

> If you’re a texter, you’ll love Messages on iPhone, iPad, and iPod
>   touch. Now they all come with iMessage, a service that’s an even
>   better kind of texting. Because it’s free for you and anyone texting
>   over Wi-Fi using an iOS device or Mac with iMessage. And it’s
>   unlimited.* So say as much as you want.

i hope it helps you..